# Should "tomorrow evening" go at the beginning or end of the sentence?

Tags: sentence-usage

Should "tomorrow evening" go at the beginning or end of the sentence?

> 1. Are you free **tomorrow evening**?
> 2. **Tomorrow evening** are you free?

Which of these sentences is correct?

Comment: Grammatically and semantically they're both fine. Orthographically they leave something to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. But the first one sounds more natural.